# Filter rows on basis of parameter provided by stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, case

I am using a SQL Server database and have a table `MYTABLE` which has data as shown below. I am trying to fetch the data from my stored procedure that accepts `@AllowedUser` as parameter. The stored procedure is currently just simple select query

```
SELECT * 
FROM MYTABLE
```

[image]

However it returns all three rows. I wanted to filter out if the returned data has any encrypted row (column: `Encryption = 1`), only then filter out this row on the basis of `@AllowedUser`. So for example, when `@AllowedUser` parameter is 3, then I will get all three rows as shown

[image]

If `@AllowedUser` is 2, then I will get first and second row as shown below (it will be same for `@AllowedUser = 1`, `@AllowedUser = 5` etc)

[image]

I had tried to to this by following way but I think it is not a good approach as I have to fetch the data twice from database

**Step 1**

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM MYTABLE
WHERE Encryption = 1 -- (I fetched this result in a parameter)
```

If that parameter's value is greater than 1 (means there is an encrypted row), then I will filter out the result according to `@AllowedUser`

**Else**

I will simply execute the select statement.

Is there any better way to perform the above task without having to call the database twice? Can I use the `CASE` statement?

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: FYI `case` is an *expression* not a *statement*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As best I can understand your requirements I think you just need a simple `OR` condition - but you still need to query the table twice to determine whether a user has an encryption row.

However since you are concerned about performance I have show a way to do it *which** appears to only need to access the table a single time.

```
DECLARE @MYTABLE TABLE (PersonId int, [Encryption] bit, AllowedUser int);

-- 36% of execution plan
INSERT INTO @MYTABLE (PersonId, [Encryption], AllowedUser)
VALUES (123,0,1),(123,0,2),(123,1,3);

DECLARE @AllowedUser int = 3;

-- 12% of execution plan
SELECT *
FROM @MYTABLE mt
WHERE(
    -- Anyone can see unencrypted rows
    [Encryption] = 0
    -- Or if the user has a row with "[Encryption] = 1" then they can see all rows
    OR EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @MYTABLE mt1 WHERE [Encryption] = 1 AND AllowedUser = @AllowedUser)
);

-- 52% of execution plan
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT PersonId, [Encryption], AllowedUser
        , MAX(CASE WHEN AllowedUser = @AllowedUser THEN CONVERT(int, [Encryption]) ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY AllowedUser) HasEncryption
    FROM @MYTABLE
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE [Encryption] = 0 OR HasEncryption = 1;
```

**BUT** this is not how SQL performance works. SQL is a descriptive language, you are describing the results you want. You are **not** telling the engine how to obtain those results. It works that out is a very complex manner taking into account indexes, statistics and other magic.

So in this simple case, when I turn on display execution plan, the CTE solution is running much slower than the double table query.

The real lesson here is, don't try and pre-optimise your query, nor assume you know how a given query is going to perform (there are some basic rules of thumb of course). The general rule is, write the query in the most clear, logical manner you can, and if there are then performance issues, performance tune those queries.

Comment: That is a very good solution but again as you suggested it also have to query the table twice. I have huge database and multiple people access the same table so It slows down the process. I was just trying to figure out how can I achieve it in a single call.

Comment: thank you for the detailed explanation. I understand what you want to convey. I think this is the best answer and approach to go with. Thank you again for taking the time to help me out.